# make an imageView move in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to make a bird jump by pressing a button. But i have not idea how to do that. I created a timer but i don't know how to use that.

```
int birdFlight;

@interface BirdViewController : UIViewController
{

    IBOutlet UIButton *flyButton;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *bird;

    NSTimer *birdMovement;

}

-(IBAction)buttonBirdFly:(id)sender;


@end
```

How to use this method?

```
    @implementation BirdViewController

    -(IBAction)buttonBirdFly:(id)sender
    {


    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should first take a few lessons in programming basics? You did not create a timer, you just defined one.

Comment: what u need is a method that moves ur image view and call that method using timer